# Definition of a topology on a set $X$: may $I$ contain uncountable many elements or is it restricted to be finite or countable?

Tags: general-topology, definition

I've the following definition of a topology $\mathcal I$ on a set $X$:

(T1) $U_a \in \mathcal I, a \in I \Rightarrow \cup_{a \in I} U_a \in \mathcal I$

(T2) $U_1, U_2 \in \mathcal I \Rightarrow U_1 \cap U_2 \in \mathcal I$

(T3) $\emptyset, X \in \mathcal I$

Now nothing is stated about $I$. I guess it is an index set or a general set ? May $I$ contain **uncountable** many elements or is it restricted to be **finite** or **countable** ?

Comment: $I$ can be any set.

Comment: @JankoBracic, so can I.

Comment: @Ahmed Are you countable or uncountable? :)

Comment: To see an actual example: one may form the topology on the real line $\Bbb R$ by $\mathcal{T} = \{U_i : i \in I\}$ where $I = \Bbb R$, and $U_i = \{x \in \Bbb R: i < x\}$. This is known as the open ray topology. Clearly, here $I$ is uncountably infinite.

Comment: Thank you, so $I$ can be any set ?

Comment: @user111854: Yes, it can.